# Getting Internal Salesforce.com Error when using StandardSetController

Tags: apex, standardsetcontroller

```
integer n = 3000;
stringQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Title, Phone From contact';
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(database.getQueryLocator(stringQuery));
setCon.setPageSize(n); // error
```

when I try to set page size as 3000 it will throw an error( Internal Salesforce.com Error).

Comment: Not quite sure but in another post, it is mentioned 2000 is the max limit here.

Comment: Have they mentioned it in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setCon.setPageSize(n)` is number of records displayed page record.

Max batch size is 2000.

If you try to execute this script in Developer Console it works fine

```
integer n = 2000;
String stringQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Title, Phone From contact';
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(database.getQueryLocator(stringQuery));
setCon.setPageSize(n);
```

And, upon changing `n=2001` and running the script, it will show you error `INVALID_BATCH_SIZE: invalid batch size: 2001`

Comment: not for pagination, but using it for other things.